# query on group to print

Tags: c#, sql

i am trying to group all users by user type add them to a list :
code:

```
   public string[] GroupByUserType()
    {
        using (DataBase db = new DataBase ())
        {
            var query = from e in db.Users
                        group db.Users by e.UserType;

            string[] groups;

            List<string> groupsByUserType = new List<string>();

            foreach (var name in query)
            {
                foreach (var item in name)
                {
                    groupsByUserType.Add(item);<--- error here
                }
            }
            groups = groupsByUserType.ToArray();

            return groups;
        }

    }
```

i get :

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Dev4\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Linq\SqlQuery\QueryOnName.cs    27  25  SqlQuery

and

> Error 2   Argument '1': cannot convert from
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table' to
>   'string'  C:\Users\Dev4\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Linq\SqlQuery\QueryOnName.cs    27  46  SqlQuery

Comment: Have you analysed the types of your variables in the debugger?

Comment: What is/are the _type(s)_ of your variables?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your linq query returns a list of `System.Data.Linq.Table`, try accessing the name property like this:

```
public string[] GroupByUserType()
{
    using (DataBase db = new DataBase ())
    {
        var query = from e in db.Users
                    group db.Users by e.UserType;

        string[] groups;

        List<string> groupsByUserType = new List<string>();

        foreach (var name in query)
        {
            foreach (var item in name["name"])
            {
                groupsByUserType.Add(item);<--- error here
            }
        }
        groups = groupsByUserType.ToArray();

        return groups;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert name toString() and then as you are making list of string

```
groupsByUserType.Add(item.Name);
```

hope this helps.